# Best way to mock filewriter

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, metaprogramming

I want to test the following method and specifically that write and close methods were called (In the case of write check what was written was what I expected). The true source code is Java and I am writing my test in Groovy. I can't use map coercion because there is no default constructor. I tried mockFor and metaClass but I can only get those working when I change the source to groovy and my unit test in groovy. Do I have any groovy options to test this code? Code below is groovy but the java method source is very similar. A real header is generated, some date logic is performed, and then the results are written.

```
class TestWriter {
    protected void writeResultToXMLFile(String response,FileWriter fw, Date today){
        String header = "header";
        try{
            fw.write(header);
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException ioe){
            String errorMessage = "Unable to write to file";
            try{
                fw.close();
            }catch (IOException ioException){
                errorMessage += ", Error attempting to close the file";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace in your code class FileWriter to Writer interface and then  you will be able to create a mock implementation for the writer and test that it receives all needed calls

Comment: I went with this answer because I was looking for a solution(if possible) that didn't need an external library like Mockito. By following this advice I was able to use map coercion for the Writer and write the unit test.

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility would be using a framework like [Mockito](https://code.google.com/p/mockito/) to mock the `FileWriter` and then `verify` that the correct values were passed.

It would look something like this:

```
// create the mock
FileWriter mock = mock(FileWriter.class);

// call the method under test and pass in the mock 

// verify the intended behaviour
verify(mock).write("the expected text");
verify(mock).close();
```

Hope this helps.